# New app design interface Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to develop APPS in C # with Xamarin, but when I open the design interface, the following error appears even without having a programmed line of code:

System.IO.IOException: Não é possível ler os dados da conexão de transporte: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto
   em System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   em System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   em Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java.JavaCommunicationContext.ReadMessageLoop() na C:\d\lanes\4985\b63523e2\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java\JavaCommunicationContext.cs:linha 227

Comment: Can you try installing Xamarin environment from Xamarin. Probably missing dll's

Comment: Some issue with your Android Simulator Kit..  and so i believe you are getting an error on JavaCommunicationContext.cs